# How to put query's result into text element and textarea element

Tags: jquery, jsp, jquery-mobile

I'm a beginner in jQuery and AJAX, and I'd just like to get a value from JSP file to HTML5
so I can put that value into a `<textarea>` which is in my HTML5 source.
Please help me and thanks.
Here is the source file:

```
<html>
..
 <body>
<div data-role="content">
<div data-role="fieldcontain"> 
    <form method="post" action="ShowQuestion.jsp" name="frm" > <!--using post action, transfer Element Information-->   
<label for="theQuestion"></label>
 <div id="QuestionLog"> <!--to contain my question title and content-->
   <input type="text" id="qnaTitle" name="qnaTitle" > </input> <!--input title-->
<textarea cols="20" rows="5" wrap="hard" id="qnaContent" name="qnaContent">
 </textarea> <!--input content-->
     </div>       
   </form>
..
</body>
</html>
```

```
Connection conn;
PreparedStatement pstmt;
ResultSet rs=null;

pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("select * from question "); // query
rs = pstmt.executeQuery(); // execute that query 

while(rs.next()) {

   String title=rs.getString(1); //save the query's result      
   String content = rs.getString(2);  //save the query's result,too

}
}catch(Exception e) {

   e.printStackTrace(); // print the Exception Message

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using jquery, after you get the value (and you are sure of it) all you have to do 
is

```
$('#qnaContent').val(content); // Considering that the result string is stored in "content"
```

Comment: how can I get two String (title, content) from jsp to html?

Comment: Let me explain what the above command does so that you can see what you want.

`$('#qnaContent')` is the handler for you textarea with "id" = "qnaContent". So if you want to access another textarea with another id lets say "id1" you write `$('#id1')`. Note that the id name is preceded by a hash "#". We prefix hash "#" to every id, and dot "." to every class. The "val()" function sets or gets the value from the textarea. If empty function is called will return the value and if a value is sent will update it.

Comment: So in you r case if you want to add text from title to another textarea change the id name and "content" to "title". And if you want to write both values to same textarea you can simply write it in val(). `$('#qnaContent').val(content + title);` Just for information, you can write text and the function as well. So it could be `$('#qnaContent').val("Content: " + content + "Title: " + title);`